# Joint probability density function methodology

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am a newbie in the field of probability theory and am trying to understand the mechanics for computing joint probability density function and everything related to this subject.
As such, I was trying to solve the following problem:
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
cxy^2(1-x)(1-y^2), & 0< x\leq 1,0< y\leq 1 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

From what I have understood, the answer is computed by:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{1}cxy^2(1-x)(1-y^2)\, dxdy = 1 $$
First, I have noticed that on some web resources, the upper limit *y* is given as *x* instead of 1 and I do not quite understand why it is so and would appreciate if someone could explain this to me.
Second, I would like to understand the mechanics of calculating double integrals such as this, after exhaustive research on the web, all I have noticed, is that there is no uniform way of doing it, and now please correct me if I am wrong but the way I have proceeded, was by initially treating *x* as a constant and thus writing it as:
$$c[\int\limits_{0}^{1}x(1-x)dx\int\limits_{0}^{1}y^2(1-y^2)\, dy]=1 $$
Then I integrate *y* followed by *x* which will lead me to compute *c=45*

Are there any flaws with this method?

Tank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{1}cxy^2(1-x)(1-y^2)\, dxdy =1$$
Then find c from this.

You are correct in your value of c = 45.

The only time the limit of integral becomes x is when you have the intervals for x and y to be $ 0<y<x$ and $0<x<1$.

As far as this problem goes, you will have limits running from 0 to 1 for both x and y.

While figuring out the limits, you have to look at the intervals for which f(x,y) is defined for both x and y

Suppose if the function was defined as this

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
cxy^2(1-x)(1-y^2), & 0< x\leq 1,0< y\leq x \\
0, & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then,

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{x}cxy^2(1-x)(1-y^2)\, dydx =1$$

That will be the one and since the of y is dependent on x, you have to integrate y first keeping x constant and then, substitute the value of x in the integrated y and now collectively integrate for x.  That should be the way.

Good luck

Satish

Comment: I am sorry, I omitted to equal the entire thing to 1, I will edit it right away.  However, would you mind, elaborating on the last part of your answer, namely when you say: "While figuring out the limits, you have to look at the intervals for which f(x,y) is defined for both x and y"